# How can I write an array of audio samples to a wav file with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, wav, javascript-oscillator

I'm writing an oscillator in JavaScript that creates a sweep(i.e. chirp) between sine wave frequencies.  For testing, I'd like to write the samples(which are floats) to a wav file.  How would I do this in Node.js?  I've seen lots of information on the browser end of things but not anything specific to Node or anything that relies on browser APIs.

Comment: there's a routine in audiorecorder.js that can do that. you don't need the whole lib, which is for browsers, but it does have that wav-making routine...

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using the minimal package `node-wav` and a snippet similar to the one below:

First, install the dependency:

```sh
npm i node-wav
```

Then, use something like

```js
let fs = require('fs');
let wav = require('node-wav');

// Parameters for the below data
const size =  5000
const amplitude = 128
const sampleRate = 20

// Generate some random data for testing
const data = (new Array(3)).fill((new Array(size)).fill(Math.random() * amplitude))

let buffer = wav.encode(data, { sampleRate: sampleRate, float: true, bitDepth: 32 });

fs.writeFile("test.wav", buffer, (err) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  console.log("test.wav written");
});
```

Considering that you already know the application of your data, you know all the "constant" parameters (size of the output, bitrate, the actual data to be written, bitdepth).

Comment: Not really important to the answer, since it's only used to generate data for testing, but I figured I'd mention that [`Math.random`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-math.random) doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: @JustinTaddei Indeed it doesn't. I fixed the "bug"

Comment: I wasn't able to get node-wav working. I found an alternative: [wav-encoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wav-encoder) which has similar syntax.

Comment: Although it hasn't been maintained for 4 years (as of writing this), `wav-encoder` is still working. Given that the wav format specs haven't changed much in the last decade (see [Sustainability of Digital Formats: Planning for Library of Congress Collections: WAVE Audio File Format](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000001.shtml)) these modules will probably all do the job (unless core node or js changes break them of course).

Answer (score -3):

You can use the built in Node.js `fs.writeFile()` api to write to a file.

By the way I see it all you have to do is loop over your audio samples, add them to a string within the iteration, and put that string into a file like so:

```
const fs = require("fs");

// Code to generate audio

let audio = "";

samples.forEach((sample) => {
  audio += sample;
});

fs.writeFile("path/to/file.wav or .mp3", audio, (err) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);

  console.log("File successfully saved!");
});
```

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then this *should* work.

Comment: Umm no: this does not create a _wav_ file

Comment: You can add .wav or .mp3 to the end of your file path whichever works for you

Comment: Oh really? So if I create a text file and change the extension to `.xls` it's now an excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Hmm... ok... my answer assumed that your data was already in .wav or .mp3 format. What format is it in if not .wav or .mp3? Also I don't know about text to excel spreadsheet but I know you can do that with .jpg to .png and back again with no problems.